# How to show the table on same page after submitting the form in html?

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, forms, form-submit

I have a form that accepts the date picker as input and sends that value to the backend and gets some response based on the input. The response data will be inserted into a table.
When the form gets submitted, it should show the table on the same page.

**HTML:**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <title>
    Date Picker
  </title>

  <link href='https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.12.1/themes/ui-lightness/jquery-ui.css' rel='stylesheet'>
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.1/jquery.min.js">
  </script>
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.min.js">
  </script>
</head>

<body>
  <form method="POST">
    Date: <input type="text" id="my_date_picker">
    <button id="sbtn">Submit</button>

    <div id="mytable">
      <table id="datatable" style="display:none">

      </table>
    </div>
  </form>
  <script>
    $(document).ready(function() {

      $(function() {
        $("#my_date_picker").datepicker();
      });
    })
  </script>
</body>

</html>
```

**JS**:

```
$("#sbtn").click(function() {
   if ($("#my_date_picker").val().length === 0){
         alert('Invalid');
         return false;
     }else {
       $("form").submit();
       $("#datatable").show();
     }
  });
```

Here I'm not able to show the table after submitting the form. Is there any way to show the table on the same page after the form submit.?

Thanks.

Comment: When you submit the form the page is going to reload. So your backend should process form submission, generate new html response with the data table and serve it back to the browser. Otherwise you have to use ajax to communicate your form data to the backed and get results back and then use javascript to render the result in your data table.

Comment: @farhodius Can you please explain either of the methods with an example.?. It would be a great help.Thanks

Comment: @Thra how are you rendering it from server ?

Comment: @Athira V Ajit, Using Python (render_template) to render the HTML page.

Comment: @Thra so I would suggest you can redirect the request to get router to re render the page , so that the updated table will be shown to the user.

Answer (score 1):

```js
  document.getElementById("button").addEventListener("click", () => {
    const val = document.getElementById("data").value
    fetch('//url/to/post/the/data', {
      method: 'POST',
      headers: {
        // if any
      },
      body: JSON.stringify({
        data: val
        // or other data
      })
    })
    .then(res => res.json())
    .then(res => {
      // response from the backend
      // assuming the data will be array and that has to be displayed as table, something like this,
      // res = {
      //   data: [{name: 'Nikhil', age: '22'}, {name: 'Hello', age: '29'}]
      // }
      const arr = res.data
      // setting the headers
      let content = '<table><tr><th>Name</th><th>Age</th></tr>';
      // setting the rows of the table dynamically
      arr.forEach((ele) => {
        content += `<tr>`
        content += `<td>${ele.name}</td>`
        content += `<td>${ele.age}</td>`
        content += `</tr>`
      })
      // closing the table tag
      content += `</table>`
      // inserting the html generated in the div with the id - result
      document.getElementById('result').innerHTML = content;
    })
    .catch(err => {
      // handle error here
    })
  })
```

```html
<html>
<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
  <title>Document</title>
</head>
<body>

  <!-- // form fields and submit button -->
  <input type="text" id="data">
  <button id="button">Submit</button>

  <!-- // table where data need to be displayed -->
  <div id='result'></div>

</body>
</html>
```

One of the possible solutions can be, you can use `fetch` or `ajax` to get the data from the backend and display it as a table, without refreshing the page.

You can learn more about it here,

AJAX - https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/AJAX

Fetch - https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Fetch_API

**EDIT:** Code added with an explanation on how to add data in the DOM as a table.

**PS:** This is one of the possible solutions on how to add data as a table, other solutions include creating the DOM using JS methods like `createTextNode()` etc.

Comment: I'm able to get the data in a table but not able to show the table. Is there any way to show the table after submitting the form..?

Comment: I will add the code snippet in the answer, demonstrating how to add data to the table in few mins

Comment: I have added the code with an explanation using comments

Comment: This code does not work

Comment: What is the error you are encountering?

Answer (score 1):

If you fetch the data in the page load itself you can use `location.reload()` after ajax submit this will reload the current page or you can append the data from the ajax response somewhat like this `$('#datatable').append(data);`

Answer (score 0):

```
/* you can use below code */
step 1: display date out of form 
step 2: get data in $_POST

if(isset($_POST)){
 /* retrieve data here  & display it */
}
```

Comment: It's always good to provide some explanation with answers rather than just a code dump. That way the OP understands better what you've proposing.

Answer (score 0):

To re render the page you can use window.location.href = window.location.href.
But since you have kept the table display as none , you have to keep a condition check there as well.

In case you are using ajax then,

```
$("form").submit(function (event) {
event.preventDefault();
var form = $(this)
url = form.attr('action')
var data = $("#my_date_picker").val()
$.ajax({
  type: "POST",
  url: url,
  data: form.serialize(),
  beforeSend: function () {
  
  },
  success: function (data) {
    $('#datatable').append(`<tr>
        <td>data</td>
     </tr>`);
   $("#datatable").show();
   
  }
})
```

});

Answer (score 0):

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head lang="en">
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <script>
    function showData() {
        document.getElementById('displaydata').innerHTML = 
                    document.getElementById("txtInput").value;
    }
  </script>

  </head>
<body>

  <form>
    <label><b>Enter Input</b></label>
    <input type="text" name="message" id="txtInput">
  </form>

  <input type="submit" onclick="showData();"><br/>
  <label>Your input: </label>
  <p><span id='displaydata'></span></p>
</body>
</html>
```

```
enter code here
```